# Error:No value has been specified for property 'checkstyleClasspath'

Tags: gradle, android-gradle-plugin

In order to check all sub projects's code style. I create a file `checkstyle.gradle` and apply it to `build.gradle` in root dir.

```
apply plugin: 'checkstyle'


subprojects { project ->

    task checkstyle(type: Checkstyle) {
        configFile rootProject.file('checkstyle.xml')
        ignoreFailures false
        showViolations true
        classpath = files()
        source 'src/main/java'
    }

    // check code style after project evaluation
    afterEvaluate {
       project.tasks.findByName('checkstyle').execute()
    }
}
```

An error occurs.

> * What went wrong:
>   >A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
>   >A problem was found with the configuration of task ':app:checkstyle'.
>       > No value has been specified for property 'checkstyleClasspath'.

I do not know why error occurs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just knew how to fix this error.

```
subprojects { project ->
    apply plugin: 'checkstyle'

    task checkstyle(type: Checkstyle) {
        description 'Runs Checkstyle inspection against ICanPlayer sourcesets.'
        group = 'Code Quality'
        configFile rootProject.file('checkstyle.xml')
        ignoreFailures false
        showViolations true
        classpath = files()
        source 'src/main/java'
    }

    // check code style after project evaluation
    afterEvaluate {
        check.dependsOn('checkstyle')
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add next for each module `build.gradle`

:

```
plugins {
...
    id 'checkstyle'
...
}
```